# Log backup vs differential backup if latter is broken

Tags: sql-server, backup

Under full recovery mode, will a differential backup "break" the previous log backups?

Let me give an example: Let's say we have the following backups:

- FULL backup 1
- Log backup 1
- LogBackup 2
- DIFF backup 1
- LogBackup 3
- LogBackup 4

Normally to restore in this situation, one would restore as follows:

- FULL backup 1
- DIFF Backup 1
- LogBackup 3
- LogBackup 4

My question is as follows: If the DIFF Backup 1-file is corrupted somehow, could I then restore the database with just the FULL and LOG backups? Like this:

- FULL backup 1
- LogBackup 1
- LogBackup 2
- LogBackup 3
- LogBackup 4

Any help is appreciated.
If this has been answered in another post, please let me know (I tried searching).

Comment: Yes, you can restore from just the log backups if the differential is unavailable.

Comment: @QueueMann Thank you. If you write your comment as an answer, I can mark it as such. (Upping your reputation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Under full recovery mode, will a differential backup "break" the previous log backups?

No. A differential backup will **not break the log chain**. Log backups rely on [LSNs (Log Sequence Numbers)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190411%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

A log chain is broken when :

- You take adhoc log backup without using `COPY_ONLY` option.
- When you change the recovery mode e.g. from full to simple.
- When you use TRUNCATE_ONLY or NO_LOG (Both deprecated in SQL 2008) or backup to `NUL` (its like taking a backup and deleting it !)
- When you revert the database from a database snapshot. For this scenario, you have to take a full backup - even differential wont work !

> If the DIFF Backup 1-file is corrupted somehow, could I then restore the database with just the FULL and LOG backups?

Yes, provided the log backups are not corrupted as well. Since differential got corrupted, there are chances that your subsequent backups **might** be corrupted.

You can even [re-initialize a secondary log shipping database from a differential backup](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/09/log-shipping-magic-using-differential-backup-delayed-secondary/) and then start applying log backups if your log backup chain is broken & provided a full backup has not ran (or you ran a full backup with COPY_ONLY option).

You have to be careful, that running a FULL backup without COPY_ONLY will reset the differential base as each differential backup will contain changes since the LAST full backup.

Read these answers as they are relevant :

- [Restricting users to COPY ONLY backups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64306/8783)
- [Finding gaps in log backups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125278/8783)